# Meteor insert record using form values

Tags: javascript, forms, input, meteor

First of all, I'm a complete JS novice. I'm experimenting with `Meteor`.**My objective is to to build a simple form that inserts records into a table**.  I've set up variables to grab values from each input, and I've placed those variables into an `insert method`. When I click the button, it recognizes the click, but doesn't pull any values from the inputs.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, I just can't figure out what it is.

**Here's the JS:**

```
var Leads = new Meteor.Collection("Leads");

if (Meteor.is_client) {

  Template.Leads.LeadsArr = function(){
    return Leads.find();
  };

  Template.AddLeads.events = {

    "click input.submit" : function () {
      var name = document.getElementById('input#name').value();
      var email = document.getElementById('#email').value();
      var type = document.getElementById('#type').value();
      var date = document.getElementById('#date').value();
      var message = document.getElementById('#message').value();

      Leads.insert({leadName : name, leadEmail : email, leadType : type, leadDate : date, leadComment : message});

    }  
  };

} // end is_client
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.getElementById expect the id, not the selector. Also, value is a property of an input, not a function. So your input queries should be like this.

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. I brought this over from jQuery, but I didn't pay attention to the context of the method or the property. Thanks!

Comment: In Meteor, jQuery should be built-in, right? So you can still do $('#name').val(), etc.